# How pass arguments to JSON inside a curl command within a Python Lambda function?

Tags: python, aws-lambda

How can I pass the value of `account_id` fetched by the below python lambda function to the json value in curl command for calling bitbucket endpoint api
CODE:

```
import json
import boto3
import os
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key


def lambda_handler(event, context):

    print('##Below Event occured')
    eventName = event['Records'][0]['eventName']
    request_status = event['Records'][0]['dynamodb']['NewImage'
            ]['request_status']['S']
    account_id = event['Records'][0]['dynamodb']['NewImage'
            ]['account_id']['S']
    
  
 
    if eventName == "INSERT" and request_status == "Approved":
        print("Condition ran Successfully")
        script = """
        curl -X POST -is -u USERNAME:PASSWORD \
        -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
        https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/workspace/repo/pipelines/ \
        -d '
        {
            "target": { 
            "type": "pipeline_ref_target",
            "ref_type": "branch",
            "ref_name": "master",
            "selector": {
            "type": "custom",
            "pattern": "create-aws-account"
        }
        },
        "variables": [
            {
            "key": "account_id",
            "value": "000000011",
            "secured": true
            }
            ]
          }'
          
        """
        os.system(script)
```

Comment: Why would you use curl from lambda, instead of a native Python HTTP client library? You've got `requests`, which is much easier to use; `libcurl`, which has literally the exact same backend implementation but is in-process and so doesn't cost a fork/exec penalty for every HTTP request; [`http.client`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html), which is built into the standard library... I can't think of any circumstance when curl is the best choice.

Comment: (Also, `os.system` is frowned on for very good reasons; you're running serious security risks by using string concatenation to generate data than's then injected into code; if you _are_ going to use `curl`, it's safer to use it from `subprocess.call(['curl', '-X', 'POST', ..., '-d', json.dumps(object_to_send)], shell=False)`, which also incidentally ensures that you're _always_ generating a JSON document, something you don't get with the f-string approach suggested by @PIG208).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Charles Duffy suggested, this approach is potentially dangerous and is subjected to malicious commands. It is not encouraged to run commands with string concatenated with unknown user inputs.

Use f-string:

```
import json

script = f"""
curl -X POST -is -u USERNAME:PASSWORD \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/workspace/repo/pipelines/ \
-d '
{{
    "target": {{
        "type": "pipeline_ref_target",
        "ref_type": "branch",
        "ref_name": "master",
        "selector": {{
            "type": "custom",
            "pattern": "create-aws-account"
        }}
    }},
    "variables": [{{
        "key": {json.dumps(str(account_id))},
        "value": "000000011",
        "secured": true
    }}]
}}'
"""
```

where `{variable_name}` is a placeholder for the value to be inserted, and `{{` and `}}` are used to escape the curly braces.

Comment: This doesn't guarantee that the values are serialized as valid JSON. Consider if your `account_id` contains a literal `"`, or ends in a backslash -- you get an output document that can't be parsed.

Comment: Moreover, because the OP is using `os.system()` and thus running the resulting string through a shell, you need to be worried about an account ID of `'$(rm -rf ~)'$(rm -rf ~)` trying to delete all the files in their home directory. (The `'`s in the proposed malicious id above cancel out the ones in the `-d '`, making content within unquoted).

Comment: I see that makes sense.